# Highlight lines of code in an editor programmatically made using jface, eclipse SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, jface

I am currently using a bunch of eclipse, jface libraries to build a small editor. I am using eclipse's [SourceViewer](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Ftext%2Fsource%2FSourceViewer.html) for it. I am trying to highlight/change the color of parts of my code in eclipse however I don't think I can use the concept of damager, repairer and PresentationReconciler because I want to highlight lines of code based on user selection. So if a user selects some code I can get the selected code by using

```
SourceViewer.getSelectionProvider().getSelection();
```

Which would return an ISelection and thats what I want to "Highlight". I am currently able to create Annotations which essentially creates squigglies under the text the user selects I would rather change the color of the selected text. Would much appreciate any help.

edit:
I am not developing as an eclipse plugin but as a standalone application using the plugin api's.

Comment: Depending on exactly what you mean by Annotation the format used for the annotation can be configured (see 'General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations' in the Preferences).

Comment: I am looking to do so programmatically I have updated the question to improve description.